# Reading fields in previous lines for moving average

Tags: awk, moving-average

### Main Question

What is the correct syntax for recursively calling AWK inside of another AWK program, and then saving the output to a (numeric) variable?

I want to call AWK using 2/3 variables:

- N -> Can be read from Bash or from container AWK script.
- Linenum -> Read from container AWK program
- J -> Field that I would like to read

This is my attempt.

Container AWk program:

```
BEGIN {}
{
...
# Loop in j 
...
k=NR

# Call to other instance of AWK 
var=(awk -f -v n="$n_steps" linenum=k input-file 'linenum-n {printf "%5.4E", $j}'
...
}
END{}
```

### Background for more general questions:

I have a file for which I would like to calculate a moving average of *n* (for example 2280) steps.

- Ideally, for the first n rows the average is of the values 1 to *k*,
  where *k <= n*.
- For rows *k > n* the average would be of the last *n* values.

I will eventually execute the code in many large files, with several columns, and thousands to millions of rows, so I'm interested in streamlining the code as much as possible.

### Code Excerpt and Description

The code I'm trying to develop looks something like this:

```
    NR>1
{
    # Loop over fields 
    for (j in columns)
    {
        # Rows before full moving average is done
        if ( $1 <= n )
        {
            cumsum[j]=cumsum[j]+$j #Cumulative sum 
            $j=cumsum[j]/$1        # Average
        }
        #moving average
        if ( $1 > n )
        {
            k=NR
            last[j]=(awk -f -v n="$n_steps" ln=k input-file 'ln-n {printf "%5.4E", $j}') # Obtain value that will get ubstracted from moving average
            cumsum[j]=cumsum[j]+$j-last[j] # Cumulative sum adds last step and deleted unwanted value
            $j=cumsum[j]/n  # Moving average
        }
    }
}
```

My input file contains several columns. The first column contains the row number, and the other columns contain values.

For the cumulative sum of the moving average: If I am in row *k*, I want to add it to the cumulative sum, but also start subtracting the first value that I don't need *(k-n)*.

I don't want to have to create an array of cumulative sums for the last steps, because I feel it could impact performance. I prefer to directly select the values that I want to substract.

For that I need to call AWK once again (but on a different line). I attempt to do it in this line:

```
k=NR
last[j]=(awk -f -v n="$n_steps" ln=k input-file 'ln-n {printf "%5.4E", $j}'
```

I am sure that this code cannot be correct.

### Discussion Questions

What is the best way to obtain information about a field in a previous line to the one that AWK is working on? Can it be then saved into a variable?

Is this recursive use of AWK allowed or even recommended?

If not, what could be the most efficient way to update the cumulative sum values so that I get an efficient enough code?

### Sample input and Output

Here is a sample of the input (second column) and the desired output (third column). I'm using 3 as the number of averaging steps (*n*)

```
N   VAL AVG_VAL
1   1   1
2   2   1.5
3   3   2
4   4   3
5   5   4
6   6   5
7   7   6
8   8   7
9   9   8
10  10  9
11  11  10
12  12  11
13  13  12
14  14  13
14  15  14
```

Comment: Please, don't post data as images. We can't use them for testing.

Comment: I second James sir here, try to post 3 simple things. 1st: sample of input file, 2nd sample of output expected, 3rd thing: sample of code for your efforts. Try to use code tags for all your codes and samples.

Comment: _What is the best way to obtain information about a field in a previous line to the one that AWK is working on? Can it be then saved into a variable?_ It can be saved to a variable and that is the best way. For example: `echo -e 1\\n2\\n3 | awk '{print $1,p;p=$1}END{print $1,p}'`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added the data in text form rather than as an image. I will also comment the code. I am currently working on Windows, so the sample of code might have to wait untill I have access to the linux shell.

Comment: Also, you could use less and simpler values for the sample and _n_. If the values are 1,2,3,4,5 and _n_=3 what's the expected output (yeah, I can't get the same values you did :)?

Comment: I'm going to do a bit of an overhaul to the post to be more compliant to the posting rules. I'll ask the most specific pressing question first, and leave the rest as a general discussion if anyone is interested. I'm also simplifying the input and output files.

Comment: Seen what you describe what you're trying to solve, you might want to use bettter tooling. Take a look at Python Pandas

Comment: this question is longer than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a running average of a single column, you can do it this way:

```
BEGIN{n=2280; c=7}
{ s += $c - a[NR%n]; a[NR%n] = $c }
{ print $0, s /(NR < n : NR ? n) }
```

Here we store the last `n` values in an array `a` and keep track of the cumulative sum `s`. Every time we update the sum we correct by first removing the last value from it.

If you want to do this for a couple of columns, you have to be a bit handy with keeping track of your arrays

```
BEGIN{n=2280; c[0]=7; c[1]=8; c[2]=9}
{ for(i in c) { s[i] += $c[i] - a[n*i + NR%n]; a[n*i + NR%n] = $c[i] } }
{ printf $0
  for(i=0;i<length(c);++i) printf OFS (s[i]/(NR < n : NR ? n))
  printf ORS
}
```

However, you mentioned that you have to add millions of entries. That is where it becomes a bit more tricky. Summing a lot of values will introduce numeric errors as you loose precision bit by bit (when you add floats). So in this case, I would suggest implementing the [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

For a single column you get:

```
BEGIN{n=2280; c=7}
{ y = $c - a[NR%n] - k; t = s + y; k = (t - s) - y; s = t; a[NR%n] = $c }
{ print $0, s /(NR < n : NR ? n) }
```

or a bit more expanded as:

```
BEGIN{n=2280; c=7}
{ y = $c       - k; t = s + y; k = (t - s) - y; s = t; }
{ y = -a[NR%n] - k; t = s + y; k = (t - s) - y; s = t; }
{ a[NR%n] = $c }
{ print $0, s /(NR < n : NR ? n) }
```

For a multi-column problem, it is now straightforward to adjust the above script. All you need to know is that `y` and `t` are temporary values and `k` is the compensation term which needs to be stored in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still very new to AWK, so give me a couple of minutes to go through the code to understand what is being done.

Comment: Great! This is really promising. I might switch to this implementation. Before marking as answered I have 2 followup questions:

1. As far as computational efficiency and resources, would this approach be better than calling AWK again recursively for the desired values (if it even is possible)? 

2. Working with an a[] array of 2280 steps* 30 columns, would the performance (speed and memory usage) loss be noticeable? What I'm trying to know is if this array size is negligible (easily manageable) by most computers. If it is I'll stay with the approach that you suggested.

Comment: To answer your questions: (1) yes this is very efficient and doing a recursive call to awk is from an efficiency point of view extremely bad as at every step you will reopen the file, process it completely. You will do this over and over and over again. It will slow the system down by a factor I don't know how much. You also will make your program run as O(n^2) while what I present here is linear. So much faster.

Comment: (2) Resource wise will be fine. In the first case you only need to remember 2280 * 30 floats, that is only 535kb of memory. Not realy a lot. With the Kahan summation, you need to remember the array + the sum + the compensation, it remains about 535kb. So nothing to worry about.

Comment: In addition to (1) since you store stuff in memory, the program does not need to reprocess that ascii string and extract the numbers (which is some computational effort), since you have them already in an array the computer knows what it has to handle.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for all of the detailed responses. One last question that I forgot before. The data that I will be working with is in scientific notation (e.g. 4.5564E-04). Is this number format still compatible with the implementation that you suggested?

Comment: No, have a look at `printf`. I suggest to use `printf "25.17e"` to print the values.